# Simplifying $|\vec{A} \times (\vec{B} \times \vec{C})|^2$

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

I know the vector identity $\vec{A} \times (\vec{B} \times \vec{C}) = (\vec{A} \cdot \vec{C}) \vec{B} - (\vec{A} \cdot \vec{B}) \vec{C}$

Now, is there a succinct way of obtaining $|\vec{A} \times (\vec{B} \times \vec{C})|^2$ using vector algebra? I know we can expand, multiply and group the terms back, but is there a neater way of obtaining the result?

Using Levi-Civita symbols, would this be easier?

Comment: You could dot it with itself - is there something wrong with the answer you get from doing that?

Comment: $|\vec{A} \times (\vec{B} \times \vec{C})|\cdot |\vec{A} \times (\vec{B} \times \vec{C})| = (\vec{A} \cdot \vec{C})^2 B^2 - 2 (\vec{A} \cdot \vec{B})(\vec{A} \cdot \vec{C}) \vec{B} \cdot \vec{C} + (\vec{A} \cdot \vec{B}) C^2$ is what I get. But, this is there a neater way of representing the terms?

Comment: Just in terms of dot products? Probably not - is there anything you're particularly expecting to see? You could say something like $|A||B||C|\sin \theta \sin \phi$ but those angles are not easy to find.

Comment: Yes, just in terms of dot products. The angles involved are not relevant for the question I am trying to solve which includes this squared term of triple product.

Comment: I hate not being able to edit a comment after a certain time. I meant to ask is there any better way of denoting the terms.

Comment: Is this for the purpose of memorising it? I think the dot product expression is quite clear, but it depends on what you want to do with the expression. i did look to see if there were any obvious simplifications you could make, but I don't think there are. If you express it with Levi Cevita (or deltas) then you might get something easier to remember, but it will be harder to read.

Comment: Yes. I encounter this expression many a times and after enough practice, the dot product expression seems okay since there is a certain pattern. I thought there could be some nicer interpretation of the resulting term if expressed in Levi Civita, as I am calculating these vectors for a physics problem. I mean of course the meaning won't change, but thought it could be easier to appreciate the concept behind it.

Answer (score 2):

Use [triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product) square equation or [exterior algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra) inner product to get

$$ (\vec{A} \cdot (\vec{B} \times \vec{C}))^2 = \begin{vmatrix} \vec{A}\cdot\vec{A} & \vec{A}\cdot\vec{B} & \vec{A}\cdot\vec{C} \\
\vec{B}\cdot\vec{A} & \vec{B}\cdot\vec{B} & \vec{B}\cdot\vec{C} \\
\vec{C}\cdot\vec{A} & \vec{C}\cdot\vec{B} & \vec{C}\cdot\vec{C} 
 \end{vmatrix}.\tag{1} $$

Now we also have the equation

$$ |\vec{A} \times (\vec{B} \times \vec{C})|^2 =
|\vec{A}|^2\  | \vec{B} \times \vec{C} |^2 -
(\vec{A} \cdot (\vec{B} \times \vec{C}))^2
\tag{2} $$

and a little bit of inspection leads to the result

$$ |\vec{A} \times (\vec{B} \times \vec{C})|^2 = - \begin{vmatrix} 0 & \vec{A}\cdot\vec{B} & \vec{A}\cdot\vec{C} \\
\vec{B}\cdot\vec{A} & \vec{B}\cdot\vec{B} & \vec{B}\cdot\vec{C} \\
\vec{C}\cdot\vec{A} & \vec{C}\cdot\vec{B} & \vec{C}\cdot\vec{C} 
 \end{vmatrix}.\tag{3} $$

The advantage of exterior algebra is that it works in $\ \mathbb{R}^n\ $ while the usual cross product is restricted to $\ \mathbb{R}^3.$

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about exterior algebra.